# Distribute pods for a deployment across different node pools

Tags: kubernetes

In my GKE Kubernetes cluster, I have 2 node **pools**; one with regular nodes and the other with pre-emptible nodes. I'd like some of the pods to be on pre-emptible nodes so I can save costs while I have at least 1 pod on a regular non-pre-emptible node to reduce the risk of downtime.

I'm aware of using `podAntiAffinity` to encourage pods to be scheduled on different nodes, but is there a way to have k8s schedule pods for a single deployment across both **pools**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes ! You can use [`Pod Topology Spread Constraints`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/), based on a label ️ key on your nodes. For example, the label could be `type` and the values could be `regular` and `preemptible`. Then you can have something like this:

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: type
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: myimage
```

You can also identify a `maxSkew` which means the maximum differentiation of a number of pods that one label value (node type) can have.

You can also combine multiple 'Pod Topology Spread Constraints' and also together with PodAffinity/AntiAffinity and NodeAffinity. All depending on what best fits your use case.

Note: This feature is alpha in 1.16 and beta in 1.18. Beta features are enabled by default but with alpha features, you need an [alpha cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-an-alpha-cluster) in GKE.

☮️✌️

Comment: In GKE it seems like nodes in a pre-emptible pool have the `cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible` key set to true. Could this be used in the selector?

Comment: yeah, but to be sure the other nodes need to have that key set to false.

Comment: Great. Yeah I think this is the case automatically in GKE node pools

Comment: Be aware that this is a kubernetes 1.16 feature, GKE stable is currently at 1.15 so this might not be available for your cluster.

Comment: oh yeah, it's alpha in 1.16 and beta in 1.18. beta is enabled by default alpha you need an alpha cluster: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-an-alpha-cluster